# How to resize and create additional thumbnail in codeignite?

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, thumbnails

I am having trouble resizing photos that I am successfully uploading in my my upload module.

I am able to upload photos to the appropriate folder, however my resizing is not working and I also want to simultaneously create a thumbnail duplicate in the same folder.

```
public function upload()
    {
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $session_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
        $this->load->model('account_model');
        $user = $this->account_model->user();
        $data['user'] = $user;
        echo $user['id'];
        $user_folder = './uploads/' . $this->session->userdata('id');
        if(!is_dir($user_folder)){
            mkdir($user_folder, 0777);
        }
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $user_folder;
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width']     = 50;
        $config['height']   = 50;

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

        $this->image_lib->resize();
        $config['upload_path'] = $user_folder;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '165';
        $config['max_width']  = '165';
        $config['max_height']  = '165';
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $data['main_content'] = '/account/upload';
            $this->load->view('includes/templates/main_page_template', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            $data['main_content'] = '/account/success';
            $this->load->view('includes/templates/main_page_template', $data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you checked your log files ?

Comment: I have and I don't see anything that would reveal the sizing not working. Do you have a suggestion of what I should be looking for or what it may be based off of my code.

Comment: Delete the log file and try to resize the image and then paste here what you have there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public function upload()
{
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $session_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $this->load->model('account_model');
    $user = $this->account_model->user();
    $data['user'] = $user;
    echo $user['id'];
    $user_folder = './uploads/' . $this->session->userdata('id');
    if(!is_dir($user_folder)){
        mkdir($user_folder, 0777);
    }

    $this->load->library('image_lib');                      #load the image manipulation library without initiatlising it here.

    $configThumb['image_library']    = 'gd2';
    //$configThumb['source_image'] = $user_folder;
    $configThumb['create_thumb']     = TRUE;
    $configThumb['maintain_ratio']   = TRUE;
    $configThumb['width']            = 50;
    $configThumb['height']           = 50;



    //$this->image_lib->resize();
    $config['upload_path']      = $user_folder;
    $config['allowed_types']    = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']         = '165';
    $config['max_width']        = '165';
    $config['max_height']       = '165';
    $config['overwrite']        = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $data['main_content'] = '/account/upload';
        $this->load->view('includes/templates/main_page_template', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        $configThumb['source_image']    = $uploadedDetails['full_path'];
        $this->image_lib->initialize($configThumb);                         #initialize the library here
        $this->image_lib->resize();                                         #resize is done here    
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $data['main_content'] = '/account/success';
        $this->load->view('includes/templates/main_page_template', $data);
    }
}
```

Full path refers to the source image that is uploaded to your server. See the **else** condition you will get the idea. Now, the change is that we are loading the library and initializing it after uploading the image and hence we are getting the **full path** from `$this->upload->data()`.

**EDIT : MY WORKING FUNCTION TO CROP AN IMAGE IN TWO DIFFERENT SIZES**

```
function udpate_profile($userId = 0){
    $data   = array();
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);echo "</pre>";
    /* Upload Image */
    if($_FILES['image']['name'] != ""){
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($_FILES);echo "</pre>";
        //echo "enter";die;

        /* Check if previous file exists */
        $chkRs  = $this->db->select('image')->where('id', $this->session->userdata['logged_user']['id'])->get('admins');
        //echo $this->db->last_query();die;
        if($chkRs->num_rows() > 0){
            $chkD   = $chkRs->row_array();
            if($chkD['image'] != ""){
                ### delete the previous image ###
                $pathActual = './profile_images/';
                $pathMedium = './profile_images/medium/';
                $pathThumb  = './profile_images/thumbs/';
                if(file_exists($pathActual.$chkD['image'])){    #delete the actual image
                    unlink($pathActual.$chkD['image']);
                }
                if(file_exists($pathMedium.$chkD['image'])){    #delete the medium image
                    unlink($pathMedium.$chkD['image']);
                }
                if(file_exists($pathThumb.$chkD['image'])){    #delete the thumb image
                    unlink($pathThumb.$chkD['image']);
                }
                ### delete the previous image ###
            }
        }
        /* Check if previous file exists */

        //print_r($_FILES['image']);die;
        $this->load->library('image_lib');

        $configUpload['upload_path']    = './profile_images/';
        $configUpload['allowed_types']  = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp|jpeg';
        $configUpload['max_size']       = '0';
        $configUpload['max_width']      = '0';
        $configUpload['max_height']     = '0';
        $configUpload['encrypt_name']   = true;
        $this->load->library('upload', $configUpload);
        /* size 64*72 for comments */
        $configThumb = array();  
        $configThumb['image_library']   = 'gd2';  
        $configThumb['create_thumb']    = TRUE;
        $configThumb['new_image']       = './profile_images/thumbs/';  
        $configThumb['maintain_ratio']  = TRUE;
        $configThumb['width']           = 64;  
        $configThumb['height']          = 72;
        $configThumb['thumb_marker']    = "";
        //$this->load->library('image_lib');
        /* size 64*72 for comments */

        /* size 167*167 for profile page */
        $configThumbMedium = array();  
        $configThumbMedium['image_library']   = 'gd2';  
        $configThumbMedium['create_thumb']    = TRUE;
        $configThumbMedium['new_image']       = './profile_images/medium/';  
        $configThumbMedium['maintain_ratio']  = TRUE;
        $configThumbMedium['width']           = 167;  
        $configThumbMedium['height']          = 167;
        $configThumbMedium['thumb_marker']    = "";
        /* size 167*167 for profile page */

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('image')){
            return 0;
        }

        $uploadedDetails    = $this->upload->data();
        if($uploadedDetails['is_image'] == 1){
            $configThumb['source_image']        = $uploadedDetails['full_path'];
            $configThumbMedium['source_image']  = $uploadedDetails['full_path'];
            $raw_name                           = $uploadedDetails['raw_name'];
            $file_ext                           = $uploadedDetails['file_ext']; 
            $imgname                            = $raw_name.$file_ext;
            $this->image_lib->initialize($configThumb);
            $this->image_lib->resize();
            $this->image_lib->initialize($configThumbMedium);
            $this->image_lib->resize();
        }
    }
    //die();
    /* Upload Image */

    $data   = $this->input->post(null);
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($data);echo "</pre>";die;
    if(isset($imgname) && $imgname != ""){
        $data['image']  = $imgname;
    }
    $this->db->where('id',$this->session->userdata['logged_user']['id'])->update('admins', $data);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I upload an image smaller than the specified dimensions, it makes it the size of the photo pre crop, and if I try to upload a photo that is bigger, it won't upload at all. Same problem I've been running into. As far as your suggestion of the 'you need to give the full path of the source image after uploading it' are you referring to the display path? Or are you referring to making the path's that are in the upload method a full path. If so not sure what you mean. thanks

Comment: Go through the code once again I have made some changes, Hope it will work now. @LightningWrist

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't upload anything at all. I've noticed that only certain sizes will allow upload at all! For example the '50' and '165' doesn't upload anything but when I have it set to 75X50 for thumb and 1024x768 for the other it will allow upload but not create a thumbnail and crop to a random size.

Comment: That's because you have set `$config['max_size'] = '165';` comment out this line first and try. If still does not uploads then print this and see the error in the `if condition` generated and let me know `print_r($this->upload->display_errors()); die;`.

Comment: Ok I did the print_r and it said the The image you are attempting to upload exceedes the maximum height or width. I need to include that anyway, however the image I am trying to upload is only 389x389 which seems reasonable. thanks for your help on this.

Comment: also this is puzzling because I was able to upload much larger images with the settings I'd stated above.

Comment: "I am trying to upload is only 389x389"? You have set the "max height" and "max width" as `165`. How will it upload images greater than that? Comment out those two lines and the images will start uploading. @LightningWrist.

Comment: this is what I have for my thumbnail $config['width']  = 50;
  $config['height'] = 50;( which is not creating duplicates WHEN uploading ) and this is what I have for my regular which is not uploading at all. $config['max_size'] = '165';
  $config['max_width']  = '165';
  $config['max_height']  = '165';

Comment: Do one thing allow the user to upload `1024*768` size of image, then crop that image in two different resolutions `16*165` and `50*50`. I'm editing the above code with one of my working solutions, hope it helps you.

Comment: Alright, I'll try to adapt this to my script. Thanks. I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

it's likely you need to pass source_image the full path of the image on the server. so if you're trying to use /uploads, then it's likely you'll need to set it as /var/www/html/uploads or whatever the full path is to that folder since the image processing is relative to the server, not the site url

Comment: That would be great if you could clarify how I'm not using the 'full path'.

Comment: say your site is me.com and the folder you want to put the image in is /images. where your site sits on the server is the full path. so if your site files sit at /var/www/html in the server's file structure, then the full path to the image directory is /var/www/html/images